# Scripting VirtualBox and isolating from existing installation

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to create an application that runs on windows. I want this application to download a "disk image" from the network (from pre-assigned server) and create a virtual machine based on it. This VM would run for a specified number of hours and then shutdown.

I want to use VirtualBox by scripting it. I found VBoxManage command and it seems to be what I am looking for. However, it seems that VirtualBox tools store their configuration as XML files in User home directory. I did learn that i can change the value of VBOX_USER_HOME environment variable to control where they are stored. However, I am not sure whether this is enough.

My problem is that the user may already have installed VirtualBox on his/her computer. I do not want my application code (and it's packaged VirtualBox binaries and conf) to mess with the existing installation.

How do I cleanly isolate my application specific VirtualBox binaries and configuration from the potentially pre-existing installed VirtualBox setup? (Even if both instances of VirtualBox binaries are being used at the same time)

I chose VirtualBox because of it's open source license and applicability of commercial use (if I compile my own binaries from the source) and because it works on Windows too (heard QEMU support for windows is still not stable). Will VirtualBox suffice for my use-case or should I look elsewhere?

Thanks for reading so far :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `VBoxManage` command really does rely on the *environment variable* `VBOX_USER_HOME` then you could write your scripts to change the environment variable to reflect your deployment for the execution of that script and its children, staying away from user data.

Comment: Yes. I intend to try this out. However, when I run VirtualBox I see some processes -> VirtualBox, VBoxXPCOMIPCD, VBoxSVC. I am worried that there might be a conflict for these processes. Was hoping that someone had a similar req before and would have some exp. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Prashanth, if you're running on Linux you may prefer to use http://libvirt.org/ to help you manage your VMs; someone has gone to some huge effort to provide an API to manage VirtualBox (among other virtualization tools) that may be easier to use than `VBoxManage`.

Comment: @sarnold. I just checked out libvirt. My use case is primarily targeted at Windows. I do intend to support Linux where I can use this. I was thinking it is sort of clumsy to script VBox on windows through VBoxManage. I'm going to check out the Python XPCOM API too.

Comment: @Prashanth, ah, I thought perhaps I mis-read your post when I saw Unix-style pathnames in your comment. :) Pity, libvirt is proving to be pretty useful...

Comment: @sarnold. Noticed that there is a experimental windows port of libvirt. http://libvirt.org/windows.html with support for VirtualBox added recently.

Comment: @prashanth, cool, if you're fine with self-labeled experimental code :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the VirtualBox SDK http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/SDKRef.pdf